# ui-router child state not reloading parent with page refresh with $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Tags: angularjs, html, gruntjs, angular-ui-router, state

This should be rather straightforward.
The goal is to remove the # in the url. To achieve this, I use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);. But that breaks reloading when on a child state.

I'm using AngularJS 1.6.4, and ui-router 1.0.0.

**I'm not looking for anything with the backend.**
 I'm just using Grunt to serve up the app. I don't need to configure any backend to do anything. It needs to be a frontend fix. Either in the ui-router, or something in the Gruntfile.

index.html, of course, has base href="/" set.

routes.module.js
    'use strict';

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name app.module:app.routes
 * @description
 * # app.routes
 * Rollup module for routes and config for parent route
 */
angular
  .module( 'app.routes', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config( routesConfig );

    function routesConfig( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider ) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); // this breaks the refreshing
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( '/' );

  $stateProvider
    .state( 'main', {
      url : '',
      component : 'main',
      abstract : true,
    })
    .state( 'main.home', {
      url : '/',
      component : 'home',
    })
    .state( 'main.admin', {
      url : '/admin',
      component : 'admin',
    });
}
```

I've just got the default Gruntfile.js, here's the connect task:

```
    connect : {
      options : {
        port : 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname : 'localhost',
        livereload : 35729
      },
      livereload : {
        options : {
          open : true,
          middleware : function( connect ) {
            return [
              connect.static( '.tmp' ),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static( './bower_components' )
              ),
              connect().use(
                '/app/styles',
                connect.static( './app/styles' )
              ),
              connect.static( appConfig.app )
            ];
          }
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after 4 trolls ridiculed me for using an outdated tech stack. Yes, I know it is 2017. But remember, half of the world's businesses are still using Windows XP, and evergreen browsers are still fully on ES5.

Anyways, found the answer from the [Github Issue 433](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/433) down to the comment by  nitin19srivastava commented on Feb 25.

### Steps to Fix:

#### 1. Add .html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('');

// app.js or router.module.js

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('');
```

[image: HTML5 mode set to true]

### 2. Install the mod-rewrite node module

```
npm install connect-modrewrite --save
```

### 3. Pull that into a variable up top of your Gruntfile.js

[image: Pulling in modRewrite package]

### 4. Replace the code under livereload > options > middleware with the following (be sure to add the extra options param):

```
        var middlewares = [];
        middlewares.push(modRewrite(['^[^\.]*$ /index.html [L]']));
        middlewares.push(connect.static('.tmp'));
        middlewares.push(connect().use(
          '/bower_components',
          connect.static('./bower_components')));
        middlewares.push(connect().use(
          '/app/styles',
          connect.static('./app/styles')));
        middlewares.push(connect.static(appConfig.app));
        options.base.forEach(function(base) {
          middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
        });

        return middlewares;
```

Or if you prefer looking at a colorful picture:

[image: Commented out original return statement, new middlewares array fix]

### 5. Restart the Grunt server!